# Post Build conditional that checks for a string containing another string (instead of ==)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a post build event like this:

> if NOT "$(OutDir)" == "Binaries\" "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)."

But what I really want to do is check to see if $(OutDir) **Contains** the word *Binaries*.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried:

> if NOT "$(OutDir)".Contains("Binaries") "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)."

But it does not work.

So, as a bonus point, what language is the "Post-Build" event supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is MS-Dos.  So most batch file kind of stuff is allowed.

Here is the command I ended up using:

> @Echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>   set BinariesVar=Binaries
>   set "PathDir=$(OutDir)"
>   IF "!PathDir:%BinariesVar%=!" NEQ "%PathDir%" (if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(OutDir).") else (if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir).")

This will use the first path is the build is not via TFS and the second path for TFS Builds.

Comment: Umm... why use the old, unmanageable, unmaintainable cmd style post-build event instead of MSBuild's `AfterBuild` event or even TFS custom activity?